# Performance for static files (HTML, CSS and JS) of PHP Server - CDN vs NGINX

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, performance, performance-tuning, cdn

Without going too much into detail to avoid that this question becomes opinion-based; so talking from a purely technical perspective: When you currently have a PHP-Apache setup, both PHP and Apache running on its most recent versions, and PHP running as PHP-FCGI, and you want to boost the performance of your static resource loads (HTML, CSS, Js, images) without impacting the great performance of your PHP processes / dynamic page loads. Which one will yield better performance improvements:

A) Switch to NGINX-PHPFPM + implement caching strategies for static resources

B) Couple existing PHP-Apache Setup with a CDN Service like AmazonCloudFront or CloudFlare (or whatever, no adv intended) which you regularly update with your static assets (HTML, CSS, Js, images)

Ignoring the obvious advantage of better global availability with a CDN; maybe just comparing the performance of static + dynamic page loads using NGINX-PHPFPM vs the CDN-solution; for the same country where the NGINX-PHPFPM Server would be located?